# pyqt: Memory Usage

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

I have a program and in it, it creates tabs, and every time I create one the memory usage goes up, but when I close a tab out the memory doesn't go down. I am just wondering, is this normal, and is there something I can do about it? Here is my code for closing out tabs:

```
def removeTab(self, index):

  text[index].deleteLater()
  del text[index] # text box

  # reorganize dict
  last = -1
  for key in sorted(text):
    if last+1 != key:
      text[key-1] = text[key]
      del text[key]
    last += 1

  self.tab_widget.setCurrentIndex(index)
  widget = self.tab_widget.currentWidget()
  self.tab_widget.removeTab(index)  # remove tab
  widget.deleteLater()
  del widget
```

Comment: I posted this on Google Plus because I would love to see this answered.

Comment: This sounds like it has to do with garbage collection; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29

Comment: have you solved it, I got similar question.

Answer (score 2):

To put it crudely:

1. The amount of memory available to a python application can grow
   during its lifetime, but it can never *fully* shrink back to where it
   started.
2. There is no way to force python to release unused memory back to the system.

So the best you can do is try to manage the amount by which the memory *grows*. One obvious way to do this is to delete unneeded objects, so that newly created objects can *re-use* the memory that has already been allocated.

But what if the application seems *unable* to re-use the memory? This either means that objects are not being deleted cleanly (i.e. there are references to them being kept somewhere), or, much less likely, that there is an underlying memory leak in PyQt/Qt.

Tracking down extra references kept to objects can sometimes be quite tricky (to say the least). Some common "hiding places" in PyQt are signals connected using lambda (or functools.partial), or monkey-patched protected methods. But there are no hard-and-fast rules for finding them.

As it stands, the example code in the question does not seem to have any places where extra references could be "hiding". So if the memory usage goes up "every time" a tab is created (as the OP claims), then the problems must lie elsewhere in the application - or to be more precise, the problems probably lie in how the objects are *created*, rather than in how they are deleted.

Comment: I spent quite a bit debuggin my seemingly memory leak issue.  After I removed lambda and partial in a deeply nested widgets, the issue is gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are using python. "Del" only removes the object reference, it does no deallocate memory. It's the garbage collector who is responsible for memory deallocation (and afaik, you can't control it).

The same will happend if you keep a reference to the object somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, someone on Google Plus gave a suggestion.

Kevin Kennedy (https://plus.google.com/u/0/105980580368438890195/posts) suggestions

".close() before .deleteLater()".

Comment: This fixed it for you? I can't see why. Seems redundant with the deleteLater().

Comment: @jdi I am not the OP. I shared this question on Google Plus because I wanted to find the OP the answer. I do not know PyQT well enough to provide the OP with an answer myself.

Comment: "Google+ is no longer available for consumer (personal) and brand accounts"

Answer (score 0):

In general memory allocated by malloc or new is not returned to the system when freed/deleted. Instead it is retained by the application and reused for later allocations. If you need to return the memory then you should look at using a custom allocator.